# Pass value to Json schema Definition

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

I'm using AJV Schema validator on NodeJS and wish to add `userID` from `sessionObject` to every incoming payload so that I can store `userID` for each transaction.

I wish to know if that can be done in json schemas.

sample Incoming Client payload -

```
Client: {
Client_Id: 12,
ClientName: 'jon',
Address: [{
Address_Id: 22,
Street: 'Sesimi Street',
City: 'Mumbai'
}
],
Contact: [{
Contact_Id: 23,
Phone: 11111111,
Email: "jon@doe.com"}]
```

Desired object post schema Validation -

```
    Client: {
        Client_Id: 12,
        ClientName: 'jon',
        UserId: 12121,
        Address: [{
        Address_Id: 22,
        Street: 'Sesimi Street',
        City: 'Mumbai',
        UserId: 12121
        }
        ],
        Contact: [{
        Contact_Id: 23,
        Phone: 11111111,
        Email: "jon@doe.com",
        UserId: 12121
}]
```

Since incoming payloads are huge, I believe it would be best to do assignments at schema validation point instead of doing recursive operations inside of my application. I'm open to suggestions.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`useDefaults`](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv#assigning-defaults) feature of AJV.

```
var ajv = new Ajv({ useDefaults: true });
var schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ClientName": { "type": "string" },
    "UserId": { "type": "integer", "default": 12121 }
  }
};

var data = { "ClientName": "jon" };

var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

console.log(validate(data)); // true
console.log(data); // { "ClientName": "jon", "UserId": 12121 }
```

To have flexibility on default value you can use [`dynamicDefaults`](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords#dynamicdefaults) with callback function. Example:

```
var uuid = require('uuid');

function getUuid(args) {
  var version = 'v' + (arvs && args.v || 4);
  return function() {
    return uuid[version]();
  };
}

var definition = require('ajv-keywords').get('dynamicDefaults').definition;
definition.DEFAULTS.uuid = getUuid;

var schema = {
  dynamicDefaults: {
    id1: 'uuid', // v4
    id2: { func: 'uuid', v: 4 }, // v4
    id3: { func: 'uuid', v: 1 } // v1
  }
};
```

Comment: `UserId` being unique to every user. I cannot use any hard coded value. I need to derive it from sessionObject

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @vearutop for your answer helped me solve my problem.

All I did was use a custom function that returns `UserId` from `sessionObject`

```
var Ajv = require("ajv");
var ajv = new Ajv({useDefaults: true,});
require("ajv-keywords")(ajv);
var definition = require('ajv-keywords/keywords/dynamicDefaults').definition;
definition.DEFAULTS.getuser = getuser;

  function getuser() {
        return sessionObject.UserId;
    }

var schema = {
  dynamicDefaults: {
    user: 'getuser'
},
 properties: {
  user: {}
 }
};
```